# Why $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k = \ln(n)$?

Tags: probability, algorithms

In the book [Introduction to Algorithms (3rd edition)](https://g.co/kgs/qWrx4L) I found this equation in a probability topic:

[image]

However, when I sum `1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5` it doesn't give me the same result as `ln(5)`

Comment: As you can see, there is an error term of order $1$ there as well. See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551025 You can also Google for Euler-Mascheroni constant, or maybe look at equation (A.7) in the book you are citing.

Comment: You are ignoring the $O(1)$ term, which represents the error.  The sum is a Riemann Sum for $\int_1^x\frac {dt}t=\ln(x)$.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960344/752069

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).